# Buildfire plugin: disableTheme meta is blocking scrolling

Tags: buildfire

I added `<meta name="buildfire" content="disableTheme">` to the HTML of my Buildfire plugin. It did indeed disable the theme CSS however it also is now preventing normal scrolling of the page. This is a simple HTML/CSS/JS plugin with no external frameworks. This is for the widget. Using BuildFireSDK version 1.15.3

The scrolling works correctly on my local environment in the plugin tester. But it does not work correctly when the plugin is loaded into a user's Control Panel or when a test app is loaded onto a device.

Is there a way to disable the theme styling but allow for normal scrolling?

Edit: I removed all the extra classes, styling and script tags from the HTML. It still does not scroll.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="buildfire" content="disableTheme">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="overflow-y:scroll;">
    <div style="overflow-y:scroll;">
        <div class="container" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <h2>Test</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Test output</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p>test value</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the theme via the meta tag, it will exclude CSS that normally would be injected into your plugin. Depending on your plugin, you may want to add additional CSS to suit your needs.

Given your example, here's some baseline CSS that you can add:

```css
html[buildfire] {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

html[buildfire] body {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify if this issue is on the widget or control side?

Comment: This is on the widget side. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the latest version of the SDK? The most recent version is currently 1.15.3.

Comment: I just downloaded it a few days ago. Version 1.15.2

Comment: I believe there was an issue that was fixed in the latest update ... I suggest updating to 1.15.3.

Comment: I updated to 1.15.3 and it still doesn't work in my test app in the Control Panel. It works fine in the local dev environment.

Comment: I added the CSS as you suggest, but it's still not working in the Control Panel. It works fine in local dev. Could you please test it on your machine and see if you can successfully scroll in the Control Panel with a simple plugin made with the above code?

Comment: Using your example with the CSS from the answer, it works for me both in the control panel and in the local plugin tester. It help to clear your cache, just to ensure that it's not a caching issue.